# mutate string in SQL using translation table without using while loop

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a translation table which has two money columns: original character, and character to replace it with. No character in column A is contained column B or visa versa. Given a string, I want to iterate through each row of my translation table, replacing each character of input string found in column A with character in Column B, and returning a fully translated result. I know how to do this with a while loop, but I'd prefer not to use one if possible as they can be slow.

UPDATE:

translation table example:

```
ColA  | ColB

%     |   P
$     |   D
```

Input string: %EN$ANT

Expected output: PENDANT

Comment: Don't describe your table structure in words, show us the table structure, sample data, and desired results.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. Add table definition(s), sample table data and the expected result.

Comment: To expand on jarlh's comment: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Comment: Create a Function to do the translation and just call it

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the database to solve this kind of problem you could either define a function that does it for you or you can do it like this:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (_from CHAR(1), _to CHAR(1), _order int);

INSERT INTO @t
        ( _from, _to, _order )
VALUES 
('%','P',1),
('$','D',2)


DECLARE @inp VARCHAR(20) = '%EN$ANT';

WITH cte AS (

    SELECT REPLACE(@inp,_from,_to)  replacement, _order FROM @t WHERE _order = 1
    UNION ALL

    SELECT REPLACE(replacement, _from,_to) , [@t]._order FROM cte
    JOIN  @t ON [@t]._order = cte._order+1
)
SELECT TOP 1 replacement 
FROM cte replacement
ORDER BY _order desc
```

Result:

```
replacement
PENDANT
```

The _order is not important, it is just there to make sure we do one replacement at a time.